# Python: How to get first 5 or last 5 from list of 10?

Tags: python, list, limit

Below searches is a list of objects (10).
Instead of hitting the database again and this time doing `(5)` to get put 5 in another variable. How would I write it below to check the variable searches to get 10 from that?

```
searches = self.get_recent_searches(10)
dic['recents'] = searches ## 10 objects
##dic['recent'] = self.get_recent_searches(5)
dic['recent'] = searches.get 5 from this list
```

**searches:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the type of searches? type(searches). IF it is dict, you only need the value, as searches = self.get_recent_searches(10)['searches'], as Corley Brigman said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `searches` is a dictionary, so you may need to deference one more time i.e.

```
searchdict = self.get_recent_searches(10)
searches = searchdict['searches']

dic['recent'] = searches[:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the first five items, you can use `searches[:5]`, which starts at the beginning and goes to (but not including) element 5. To get the last five items, you can use `searches[-5:]`, which starts from item -5 (which translates to the fifth item from the end) and goes to the end of the list.

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: unhashable type` when I try that :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you could use slice, like :

```
dic['recents'] = searches[:10]
```

The slice is used to get part of the list, in form of :

```
content[begin : end]
```

Python list is zero index based. And begin(th) element is included in the result, while the end(th) element is exlusive. If you want to first i elements, please use searches[:i]. If the last i elements are needed, searches[-i:] works well.

Hope it be helpful!

Answer (score -1):

To get the first or last 5 out of your list you can use list comprehension. See below:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

#puts first 5 elements in new list
first_five = [x for x in my_list[0:5]]
print first_five

#puts elements after index 5 into new list
last_five = [x for x in my_list[5:]]
print last_five
```

Comment: This list comprehension is just a longer version of doing `my_list[:5]`, and I don't think it really adds anything. Also, your second solution won't work if there are anything but ten items in the list (though I guess that's guaranteed in this specific example).

Comment: The second statement is exactly how I intended it and the comment was supposed to explain it. All elements after the object at index five will be placed in the new list.

Comment: ok, well in that case your intended solution only works if you have exactly ten elements, so it's not as useful as the other suggestions.